# Ambiences with intelligible speech or not?

Tags: ambience, editing

Hi all!

First of all, a BIG thanks to everyone at this forum, I've been learning a lot from you lately.

Here is a tiny question regarding ambiences and people talking. Do you see to it that it is not heard what people say in a recording of for example a street or do you just leave it in when editing?

I'm not speaking in a legal sense since that is not really a problem where I come from but more of what would take you out of the moment watching the movie. Maybe a kid walking by whining at his dad to get ice cream witch might be fine in one scene but weird in winter for example. Take it out, leave it in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take discernable dialogue out (especially where they don't have a motivated contextual purpose), or mangle it so the words of the callout aren't intelligable. Ensures there's no distraction and that the BGz are fully M&E compatible.

Comment: That makes absolute perfect sense. I just think it adds something that would be very time-consuming to add later. Although this would call for a very extensive library... Yea, all go with your method.